# FCM Notification not firing when app is killed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM notifications work for me when the app is in background or in foreground but not when the app is killed.

Here's my  FCM configuration code:

```
 Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
class CategoriesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/view-cateogries';
  _CategoriesScreenState createState() => _CategoriesScreenState();
}

class _CategoriesScreenState extends State<CategoriesScreen> {
  Future _screenFuture;
  void initState() {
    _saveDeviceToken(FirebaseMessaging.instance);
     FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    super.initState();
  }
```

I have read numeruos articles online and here on stackoverflow. For instance, one of the suggestions was to disable battery saver. I have tried that but no luck. Any ideas what I am missing?

I am using firebase-messaging version **^10.0.2**

Comment: Looks like you are still using the older version, start by migrating & follow this guide for background handling: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages

Comment: @DarShan, what do I need to migrate to?

Comment: Is this only with Android or IOS too?

Comment: Android for now but in the future, I will face the same issue with ios am sure.

Comment: This is simply not possible

Comment: @RobinDijkhof, why is not possible?

Comment: Did you prioritize the FCM JSON Request ?
Because I'm able to get FCM, even app is killed (swipe away from recent screen) on Android and IOS also.
I'm using data notification, and I got the response on the android. For IOS, it's a bit tricky

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're calling the `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()` method inside `initState()` of a stateful widget which is not allowed as it is stated in the documentation:

> Since the handler runs in its own isolate outside your applications
> context, it is not possible to update application state or execute any
> **UI impacting logic**. You can however perform logic such as HTTP
> requests, IO operations (updating local storage), communicate with
> other plugins etc.

You should set the background messaging handler before `runApp()`:

```
/// Define a top-level named handler which background/terminated messages will
/// call.
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initialize Firebase App
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // Run your app
  runApp(HomeScreen());
}
```

Check [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you getting notification while in foreground and background state and not in terminated state it's may not only because of your code. If you are running in debug mode then try totally terminate the application and launch without through IDE, launch from mobile/simulator. Android OS will restrict background activity while debugging this may cause to avoid the notification from firebase.

Comment: After hours of debugging and going down a rabbit hole, you literally saved my sanity for the day, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When the App is killed the only way to "do something" when FCM wants to trigger some behaviour is by using a BroadcastReceiver: https://chloe-thhsu.medium.com/a-simple-way-to-combine-fcm-notification-with-tts-b48a777ec84f (you need only one piece of example code at this link)

FCM should trigger some Intent and only registered App will receive it and do something.

BroadcastReceivers works even when the App is closed/killed, but them allow only basic "actions" when them are triggered. For you it could be usable: "*start and Activity using an Intent by passing XYZ argument*" where your App/Activity will be launched and you can do "all what you want" from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the notification onMessage function is by simply getting all the data in the data key instead of notification key. The data that is being send, please update the key from notification to data.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't trigger the notification. I changed notification to data, ran firebase deploy, restarted my app and tried it but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Handling FCM notifications in the background even when app is terminated has been there for quite some time now. The steps

```dart
  void _setupFCM() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    // The function passed here will be fired when app is in background and when app is terminated
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
    //...
    //...
    // This is fired when app is in foreground
    });
  }
```

Only thing to keep in mind is that the function passed for firing upon background **has to be an anonymous function**, that is it should be outside any class. The function will be executed in a separate isolate, so you can perform any kind of non tasks like network call, show a notification, update database etc (anything that does not involve UI).
You can find more documentation [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/)

EDIT- I may have misread the question a bit. The answer above is for times when you want to handle something when a notification is received. As for the notification, unless it is a data notification, a notification should pop up on its own. You can generate your own notification using something like [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) in the callback itself as well!

Comment: your assumption is correct. I do want to handle notifications when the app is in foreground, background and killed. I tried to follow your instructions and created a function outside class and referenced it inside the class but I still do not get notification when the app is killed. I have installed the app in two phones. The app with admin login is supposed to receive the notification. It gets notified when an order is created while in foreground and background, but not when the app is killed. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Can you say what version of firebase_messaging you're using

Comment: This is what I am using:  firebase_messaging: '>=0.0.7 <9.1.0'

Comment: I think you should update it to the latest and try, firebase_messaging: ^10.0.2. Even the syntax has changed because fcm.configure() had some issues

Comment: I did that but still no notification when app is killed. Please see my code.

Answer (score 0):

**use `@pragma('vm:entry-point')`**

It must be annotated with @pragma('vm:entry-point') right above the function declaration (otherwise it may be removed during tree shaking for release mode).

[Official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#:%7E:text=It%20must%20be%20annotated,(MyApp())%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use OneSignal for push notifications. It is more stable and always receive notifications. (Even when the app is killed).